# How to shut off a certain process on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I have some .exe name i want to terminate if its running, how?

**Edit:** I modified mike's example to this, and its perfect:

```
WinExec("taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F", SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: You tagged this c++.  Are you looking to do this killing programmatically?  If so give us more details.  If you just want to zap a process on your desktop then this belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: i wouldnt be tagging this as c++ if i didnt want to do that, i edited now my message...

Comment: I was not the person who voted to close, so at least one other person thought you were asking a question to which the answer was "Task Manager".   After all you could have been asking how to kill a runaway C++ process.

Comment: `WinExec` is deprecated; use `ShellExecute()`.

Comment: You're working in C/C++? So use the APIs, don't depend on external programs. Taskkill doesn't even exist on Windows pre-XP (IIRC), and you can't get any feedback on the result of its work. You don't even have to study a lot the PSAPIs, the code to kill a process can be found easily (see Kyle Rozendo's answer).

Comment: he pasted 4 possibilities, i dont want to choose one of them, i asked best way. oh wait, i didnt ask best way, i should have. i thought its obvious i want best way, instead of finding it out myself from dozen of docs and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of a process to kill, for example notepad.exe, use the following command from a command prompt to end it

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```

This will cause the program to terminate gracefully, asking for confirmation if there are unsaved changes. To forcefully kill the same process, add the /F option to the command line. Be careful with the /F option as it will terminate all matching processes without confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Without trying to be rude, but just use Google? Here's what I found in a quick search:

- [How to kill a process given a name](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/killprocess.aspx)
- [Find and kill a process which uses the specified loaded dynamic library (.dll)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/freelib.aspx)
- [how to kill a process in C++?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-kill-a-process-in-c-194314/)
- [C++ : Forums : General C++ Programming : Process::Kill()](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6497/)

Comment: yeah which one of those are the best?

Comment: Look at the code project ones. They're rated by programmers, so the better ranking, the better (in general).

Comment: Google can turn up all sorts of stuff, frequently of dubious relaibility.  It requires a certain amount of expertise to assess whether the top hits in Google are correct or safe (especially as they can contradict each other).  This is a general observation, and I am not maligning any of the links you have posted.